# Is it possible to put conditions so that series is convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let be $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ a sequence so that of its terms belongs in $(0.1)$ as $(\frac{1}{n^2})_{n\in\mathbb N }$ and $(\frac{1}{n})_{n\in\mathbb N}$.

So if we put

$$ \begin{cases}
a_n=\frac{1}{n}, \\
b_n=\frac{1}{n^2},
\end{cases}
\qquad\text{we find}\qquad
\begin{cases}
\sum a_n \text{ is divergent,} \\
\sum b_n \text{ is convergent.}
\end{cases} $$

This is clear. But the question that came to my mind. Is it possible to find condition for $\sum x_n $ to be convergent?

If we observe the example above we find that these terms belongs to $(0.1)$ and written in the form $(\frac{1}{q^s})$ where $q\in\mathbb N$.

For this we set the condition that it be $s \succ 1$.

And in the general case in which this term in $(0.1)$, how do we deal with this series?

Comment: I would be surprised if such a general test for convergence exists. There are many series for which the question of convergence/divergence is so challenging and not known in contemporary mathematics, such as in the [Flint Hill series](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FlintHillsSeries.html).

Comment: What is $(0.1)$?